# Sql in Snowflake changing date from 106(13-APR-2020) to 105(13-04-2020)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, to-date

So I have a couple date fields in a table that are formatted as `(DD-MON-YYYY)` and I need to convert them to `(DD-MM-YYYY)` The field itself is already a `VARCHAR`. In Snowflake, how would I make this change. Here is what I have done so far.

`select to_date(end_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') from`

`error: Can't parse '31-JAN-2020' as date with format 'dd-mm-yyyy'`

Answer (score 0):

An easy way for you to approach this is to convert your string to a date, and then back to a string in the new format, an example follows:

```
--create an example table to test
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xyz (my_dt_string VARCHAR(100));

--insert a couple records
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES ('31-JAN-2020'), ('13-APR-2020');

--test a conversion, from string to date back to string
SELECT  my_dt_string, 
        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(my_dt_string, 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy') converted 
FROM    xyz;

--looks good? run the following
UPDATE xyz 
SET my_dt_string = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(my_dt_string, 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy');

--take a look
select * from xyz;
```

I hope this helps...Rich

Answer (score 0):

The `to_date()` function provides you the ability to convert a VARCHAR field to a DATE field, not specify the format of the date.  So, you'd want to run this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

This will output the date as a date.  If you want to specify how you see a date, you have 2 choices:

First, convert it back to a VARCHAR in your preferred format:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Second, change your session parameter `DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT` to be the format you'd like to see dates displayed:

```
ALTER SESSION SET DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
```

This could also be done for a user, rather than a session using:

```
ALTER USER SET DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
```